# Getting an xml attribute with XPAth using c#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I'm trying to get an attribute from the XML but I'm getting an error:

> *Expression must evaluate to a node-test*

I'm new to XPath.

XML file example:

```
<Message>
   <Head>
      <Sender Identifier="id" ref=""/>
   </Head>
</Message>
```

Code:

```
XPathDocument xDoc = new XPathDocument("documentName.xml");
XPathNavigator nav = xDoc.CreateNavigator();
XPathNodeIterator xpathNode = nav.Select("/Message/Head/Sender/[@Identifier]");
//This is where I get the error.
```

And I'm also not sure how to display the attribute value.

Comment: I did but ass it but its not showing up, im nto sur ewhy

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
/Message/Head/Sender[@Identifier]
                    ^
                    |->no need of / here since Identifier is an attribute of sender
```

So,

`/Message/Head/Sender[@Identifier]` would only select Sender if it has an `Identifier` attribute

`/Message/Head/Sender[@Identifier='id']` would only select Sender if it has an `Identifier` attribute with value `id`

Comment: +1. Good explanation. Usual note - if `id` contains single qoute you'll need to do `concat` tricks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the wonderful tool to evaluate Xpath of the given XML

go to this link http://www.xmltoolbox.com/ and try to paste your xml in the textarea and move your cursor to the node you want Xpath.Xpath will be generated below

Answer (score -1):

```
 XmlIO xml = new XmlIO(xmlPath);
                ProductName = xml.SelectNodeValue(@"//PRODUCTINFO/Application/@ProductName");
                IDictionary<string, string> keyValList = xml.SelectNodesList(@"//PRODUCTINFO/Application/Parameters");
```

Take a look